# Referenced bean 'org.springframework.security.securityContextSource' not found

Tags: spring, spring-security

I am configuring spring security ldap. But in spring-security.xml, m getting this warning

```
Referenced bean 'org.springframework.security.securityContextSource' not found
```

on `<security:authentication-manager>` line

Can anyone tell me, what can be the problem???

Answer (score 1):

Please ensure you have in dependencies spring-ldap-core.
Example for 3.1.3

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-ldap</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.3.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the dependency requirement, make sure your `ldap.xml` configuration file (in which I expect your bean is actually declared) is referenced in `web.xml`, but from the sounds of things, Michael's answer is probably correct.