# Spring Security 3.1 LDAP Active Directory Issue

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-ldap

I am trying to setup LDAP with Active Directory and getting below error, I am new to spring security. I am using Spring core 3.2 and spring security 3.1, could some one help....

```
    org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.filterChains': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain#13' while setting bean property 'sourceList' with key [13]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain#13': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter#0' while setting constructor argument with key [1]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter#0': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager#0' while setting bean property 'authenticationManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager#0': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'org.springframework.security.config.authentication.AuthenticationManagerFactoryBean#0' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.config.authentication.AuthenticationManagerFactoryBean#0': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.authenticationManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'myLdapAuthProvider' while setting constructor argument with key [0]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'myLdapAuthProvider' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/context/webappContext-security.xml]: Resolution of declared constructors on bean Class [org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.ad.ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider] from ClassLoader [WebappClassLoader
  context: /myApp
delegate: false
 repositories:
/WEB-INF/classes/
----------> Parent Classloader:
 org.apache.catalina.loader.StandardClassLoader@75e4fc
 ] failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:     org/springframework/ldap/NamingException
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:329)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:107)
```

my wepappSecuroty-context.xml is,

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
     <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:sec="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd">

<sec:http pattern="/public/login.jsp" security="none"/>
<sec:http pattern="/index.jsp*" security="none"/>
<sec:http pattern="/images/**" security="none"/>
<sec:http pattern="/js/**" security="none"/>
<sec:http pattern="/public/**" security="none"/>
<sec:http pattern="/styles/**" security="none"/>
<sec:http pattern="/services/**" security="none"/>
<sec:http pattern="/public/login.jsp" security="none"/>


<sec:http use-expressions="true" entry-point-ref="loginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint">
    <sec:intercept-url pattern="/ui/login.do" access="permitAll"/>
    <sec:intercept-url pattern="/ui/**" access="isAuthenticated()"/>
    <sec:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="isAuthenticated()"/>
    <sec:form-login login-page="/public/login.jsp"/>
</sec:http>
<bean id="loginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint"
      class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint">
    <property name="loginFormUrl" value="/ui/login.do"/>
</bean>
<bean id="securityFilter"
      class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter">
     <property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager"/>
    <!--  When user provides correct username/password and authentication is successful -->
    <property name="authenticationSuccessHandler"
              ref="authenticationSuccessHandler"/>
</bean>
<sec:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
    <sec:authentication-provider ref="myLdapAuthProvider"/>
</sec:authentication-manager>
<bean id="myLdapAuthProvider"
      class="org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.ad.ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider">
    <constructor-arg value="xxxx"/>
    <constructor-arg value="ldaps://xxxxx:1111/DC=ent,DC=yyy,DC=xxxx,DC=corp"/>
    <property name="convertSubErrorCodesToExceptions" value="true"/>
    <property name="useAuthenticationRequestCredentials" value="true"/>
    <property name="authoritiesMapper" ref="grantedAuthoritiesMapper"/>
</bean>

<bean id="grantedAuthoritiesMapper" class="com.blah.security.MyAuthorityMapper"/>

<bean id="authenticationSuccessHandler"
      class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler">
    <property name="defaultTargetUrl" value="/ui/home.do"/>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:     org/springframework/ldap/NamingException
```

Have you added the corresponding jar (spring-ldap.jar) to your classpath ?

If so, check spring-ldap.jar's version against your spring-core.jar's version.

Comment: Thanks Majid, that solved this issue. I got other errors came up, not related to this, though.

Comment: Great (+1). I have answered the similar question some time ago: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16208672/referenced-bean-org-springframework-security-securitycontextsource-not-found/16211899#16211899. Sometimes people not accept the correct answer :(

Comment: Could you also please check this Question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16697925/spring-security-with-ldap-and-database-roles