# Type JdbcDaoSupport cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files error

Tags: java, spring

I wanted to follow [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16697925/spring-security-with-ldap-and-database-roles) from SO and tried to add the following code:

```
public class CustomJdbcUserDetailsService extends JdbcDaoImpl {

    @Override
    public List<GrantedAuthority> loadUserAuthorities(String username) {
        return super.loadUserAuthorities(username);
    }

}
```

in my Spring-Boot Project. Sadly I get the output:

```
The type org.springframework.jdbc.core.support.JdbcDaoSupport cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files
```

So on research I tried to add some new dependencies (like suggested [here](http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/web/56120-strange-error-the-type-org-springframework-dao-support-daosupport-cannot-be-resolved))

e.g.:

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

but it does not help. I tried to refresh (clean) the project but nothing changed. Can someone relate to this issue? I am using Spring Tool Suite btw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using SpringBoot ,you can simply add the JDBC starter to your pom.xml in order to have JDBC support.

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

It will transitively give you `spring-jdbc` , `spring-tx` and `HikariCP`

You also need to include the JDBC driver in your pom.xml depending on what DB you are using.

Also remember to configure the DB access info in your `application.properties` , for example in case of Postgresql:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:5432/
spring.datasource.username=admin 
spring.datasource.password=password
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try below steps in order:

1. Add `spring-jdbc` dependency
2. Do maven force update
3. Delete `.m2/repository` folder and then do maven update as this can also happen due to corrupted local maven repository