# How to implement Spring Security with LDAP and Role based granted authorities from database?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security, ldap

I am working in a Spring MVC Thymeleaf project where LDAP security with Database and Role-based granted authorities is a must-have requirement from the end-user.

**What I need**

- Primary authentication should be performed by LDAP
- User Role and granted authorities must be configured in the database along with LDAP user name

> ```
> example: 
> LDAP user: nahid@test.com
> Role: Admin
> Granted Authorities for "Admin" role: permission_x,permission_y etc
> ```
>
> Which will be used in web page as "hasAuthority("permission_x")"

- After LDAP Authentication, System will check if User Exist in the database as a white list user
- After the white list check, roles and privileges will be loaded for the user and authorization will be imposed for loaded permissions(not role)

**What I found is here:**

- [Spring Security with LDAP and Database roles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16697925/spring-security-with-ldap-and-database-roles), which is a bit outdated
- https://spring.io/guides/gs/authenticating-ldap/ where only LDAP authentication is shown.
- https://www.baeldung.com/role-and-privilege-for-spring-security-registration Granted Authority example

**Now my questions are:**

1. Do I need to store LDAP Password with LDAP user Name? If yes, is it safe?
2. Is there any example that exists for the above scenario?
3. Will fine-grained granted authorities work for LDAP users?

How LDAP authentication and jdbc based authorization will work together?
Can anybody help?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 9):

Since I have found a solution, I am sharing my own answer here. Hope it will help others:

**My Answers are:**

1. No Password needs to be stored in the database.
2. Not exactly
3. Yes, fine-grained granted authority works perfectly for LDAP users

**How I solved my problem:**

**Step 1:**

The trick is using a **UserDetailsContextMapper** with **UserDetails** provided by regular **UserDetailsService**.

example:

```
 @Override
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth
                .ldapAuthentication()
                .userDetailsContextMapper(userDetailsContextMapper())
                .userDnPatterns("uid={0},ou=people")
                .groupSearchBase("ou=groups")
                .contextSource()
                .url("ldap://localhost:8389/dc=springframework,dc=org")
                .and()
                .passwordCompare()
                .passwordEncoder(new BCryptPasswordEncoder())
                .passwordAttribute("userPassword");
    }


 @Bean
    public UserDetailsContextMapper userDetailsContextMapper() {
        return new LdapUserDetailsMapper() {
            @Override
            public UserDetails mapUserFromContext(DirContextOperations ctx, String username, Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities) {
                UserDetails details= userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(username+"@test.com");
                return  details;
            }
        };
    }
```

After successful LDAP authentication, it will try to load valid registered user to the context with all granted authorities.

**Step 2**

**hasAuthority** didn't work for me. I have used something like below:

```
<div sec:authorize="hasRole('SOME_PRIVILEGE')">
            <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
                This is secret DIV
            </div>
        </div>
```

For a quick check, you can use below:

```
<span sec:authentication="principal.authorities"></span>
```

I hope it will help somebody someday.

Happy Coding!

**Edit:**
[For LDAP over SSL and Spring Boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6431383/using-spring-ldap-with-ssl)

Comment: what if the user cannot be found in userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername

Comment: handle it gracefully by showing message "user not found"